# Scaling only one object in a scene-OpenGL 3.0

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I have a scene with two cubes, and I would like to be able to only scale one cube. Basically, what I want to do is when I press the S uppercase key, the cube will continue to become larger as longer as I continue to press uppercase S, and when I press lowercase s I want to be able to make the cube smaller as long as lowercase s is pressed.

I have run into two problems:

1. I do not know how to detect whether the key pressed is lower case or upper case.
2. My entire scene (as in both cubes) enlargen and shrink when I press the keys.

Here is my code for the keys:

```
void keyPressed(GLFWwindow *_window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {

// Control the state of keys pressed
if (action == GLFW_PRESS)
    keys[key] = true;
else if (action == GLFW_RELEASE)
    keys[key] = false;

switch (key) {
    case GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE: glfwSetWindowShouldClose(_window, GL_TRUE); break;

    // Change between points, lines and fill
    case GLFW_KEY_P: glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, getMode('P')); break; 
    case GLFW_KEY_W: glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, getMode('W')); break; 
    case GLFW_KEY_T: glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, getMode('T')); break;

    case GLFW_KEY_S: scale_matrix = scale(scale_matrix, vec3(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f));

                     //model_matrix = scale(model_matrix, vec3(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f));
                     break;

    case GLFW_KEY_R: scale_matrix = scale(scale_matrix, vec3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));
                     //model_matrix = scale(model_matrix, vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f));
                     break; 


    //Reset camera
    case GLFW_KEY_D: cameraPosition = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                     view_matrix = lookAt(
                        cameraPosition,
                        vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -100.0f),
                        vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)); 
                     break;
    default: break;
}
return;}
```

Since I wasn't sure on how to detect uppercase and lower case, I assigned R as the key to shrink the scene. This is the code for my cube positions:

```
glm::vec3 cubePositions[] = {
glm::vec3(0.0f,  0.0f,  -1.0f), 
glm::vec3(2.0f, 10.0f, -10.0f), 
};
```

What I have tried so far was to use an if statement for case: GLFW_KEY_S to check for the cube position but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Most libraries do not recognize uppercase vs. lowercase keys. You should do this on your own by detecting that also Shift key is pressed at same time...

For scaling. You need to multiply your matrix by scale matrix only before rendering of one cube and then return to previous state. If you use OGL matrix system you shouold do it like this.

If using the fixed function pipeline:

```
glLoadIdentity();
glMultMatrix( view_matrix );
// 1st cube
glPushMatrix();
glMultMatrix(scale_matrix);
drawCube();
glPopMatrix;

// 2nd cube
glPushMatrix();
drawCube();
glPopMatrix;
```

If using shaders:

```
mat4 modelview;

modelview = view_matrix;
glUniformMatrix4fv(location_modelview,  1, GL_FLASE, modelview);
drawCube();

modelview = view_matrix * scale_matrix
glUniformMatrix4fv(location_modelview, 1, GL_FLASE, modelview);
drawCube();
```

If you are multiplying your matrices yourslef, you should keep different object->world matrix for every object in scene separately.

I wouldn't bother with deprecated function now. Just get what you want first and try to find out how to do it better later.

Comment: OP may not be using the fixed function pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

> One is that I do not know how to detect whether the key pressed is lower case or upper case

For that you test if a *modifier key* has been pressed, in your case the "shift" modifier key.

> and the second is that my entire scene (as in both cubes)

OpenGL is a drawing API, not a scene graph. So the trick is to apply that scaling matrix only when drawing the models that should be scaled and omit it for the rest.